Is this normal in an electrolyzer?
I made a dry cell electrolyzer using graphite foil. I hoping for minimal corrosion, but only after some time of running, the both the anodes and cathodes are destroyed. Picture at the bottom. Does anyone know the reason for this?
One reason may be that I had been running it at a low voltage, less than 1.5 V. It had been putting hydrogen but it was super slow. That might’ve destroyed the cells.
Edit: Graphite foil is from amazon. The current was 5 amps. Duration was for like 1 hour, but there was very, very little hydrogen production. Is this normal amounts of corrosion because it seems like a lot. Idk temp. Electrolyte solution was 20% potassium hydroxide(KOH) and 80% water.



What type of graphite foil? What electrolyte, what current, what temperature, what duration...

@DrMoishePippik Graphite foil is from amazon. The current was 5 amps. Duration was for like 1 hour, but there was very, very little hydrogen production. Is this normal amounts of corrosion because it seems like a lot. Idk temp.

https://www.amazon.com/MinGraph-Flexible-Graphite-Thickness-Homogeneous/dp/B07K8Y4269/ref=asc_df_B07K8Y4269/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=692875362841&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=4769097003893457300&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9032190&hvtargid=pla-2281435178618&mcid=960a17eadabf3cfe90237a7823c7a9d8&hvocijid=4769097003893457300-B07K8Y4269-&hvexpln=73&gad_source=1&th=1

Could  it be that the graphite was reacting with oxygen to produce carbon dioxide - graphite electrode cells have to often be replaced from this

Why would it do that and is there a way to prevent it? @ChemLover68

Graphite is vulnerable to mechanical erosion by forming microbubbles or other products, not to chemical corrosion.

@Poutnik When I look it up, people say that the graphite reacts with oxygen liberating Carbon Dioxide. There is even a forum question with this. Apparently graphite is used though as it is easier to oxidize than Oxygen Anions https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/why-do-they-use-graphite-electrodes-in-the-hall-h%C3%A9roult-process

@Anish Kommireddy The main one I know is just to replace Graphite electrodes. Also what was the electrolyte in the process.

@ChemLover68 But it is at very different conditions.
